How to create a template for a post in Query Loop block?
Let's say I want to use WordPress' block builder to construct a page, and for one of the sections I use the Query Loop block. In the "List View" (layers panel sidebar) I can add and remove blocks from each result / item, which is called a "Post Template".
But sometimes I need far more control over the HTML that gets output. I want to write custom HTML that gets output when using a Query Loop block. Specifically, I want to make an HTML template in my custom theme that prints the output of an item.
Is that possible, and how can be it be done?
I've done loads of searching online and found nothing. The Query Loop block is fairly useless to me when doing advanced theming if I can't customise the HTML in my theme.

I think that it's designed to be simple and straightforward because it's not intended for developers to use but rather fo 'users' to use.  If what you need is an HTML template with a custom loop/query, then roll your own template that does exactly what you want it to.
